# mysql query issue with Farsi and Arabic charecters

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

there is a problem when I'm trying to run a search query in my table and the problem is that some data in my table has arabic and farsi characters.For example the characters like  "ي" which is arabic and "ی" which is farsi or "ك" and "ک".
or even in farsi there is "ا" and "آ".

How should I run the search query so different version of arabic and farsi characters will be searched ?

Thanks

Comment: So, if you search for one of these characters, do you want to return text containing all similar letters, not just the specific you used?

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to the database with PHP, try setting the **charset**.

`SET CHARSET utf8`